# How to format numbers on multidimensional arrays in php?

Tags: php, number-formatting

Sorry, my question is probably an easy one, but I don't know PHP, and after hours of surfing the net, I couldn't make it work :/

I'm doing a website with a list of prices, that I put in an array:

```
$priceList = [
    "teaTowel" => [
        "calm500"   => 2.75,    "active500" => 3.25,
        "calm300"   => 3.15,    "active300" => 3.65,
        "calm150"   => 3.50,    "active150" => 4.00,
        "calm50"    => 3.90,    "active50"  => 4.40
    ],
    "apronChild" => [
        "calm500"   => 3.30,    "active500" => 3.45,
        "calm300"   => 3.70,    "active300" => 3.85,
        "calm150"   => 4.20,    "active150" => 4.35,
        "calm50"    => 4.90,    "active50"  => 5.05
    ]
];
```

I managed to display them (yay !), like so:

```
<p>Price: <?php echo $priceList['apronChild']['calm500'] ?> &euro;</p>
```

The problem is, I would like to format the prices so that they appear with a comma instead of a point, and two decimals. Like "3,30" instead of "3.3"

But I can't make the function format_number work on my array :/

I tried endless variations of this:

```
$priceListFormat = array_map(function($num){return number_format($num, 2, ',', ' ');}, $priceList);

<p>Price: <?php echo $priceListFormat['apronChild']['calm500'] ?> &euro;</p>
```

But there's no way around it, I know nothing about php and I'm kind of stumbling in the dark here ^^
Thanks for your help !

Comment: Welcome to SO! The question could be clearer--if the only problem is number formatting, and you're OK manipulating the array, I recommend dropping all of the array code and focusing solely on the format problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this with `array_map()`, because it doesn't return an associative array. You have to use nested loops.

```
$priceListFormat = [];
foreach ($priceList as $k1 => $v1) {
    $r1 = [];
    foreach ($v1 as $k2 => $v2) {
        $r1[$k2] = number_format($v2, 2, ',', ' ');
    }
    $priceListFormat[$k1] = $r1;
}
```

Comment: Hm, tried it but I get a bunch of errors:

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\pegasus\include\pricelist.php on line 28

Comment: Oops, I thought it was 3-dimensional. Give me a minute

Answer (score 1):

If your array just contains prices, then you can use `array_walk_recursive()` which will just process all of the leaf nodes of the array.  Then just format each value and replace the existing value with it...

```
array_walk_recursive($priceList, function(&$price) 
                {$price = number_format($price, 2, ',', ' ');});
```

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get your proposition to work... :)
I really suck at php ^^
Thanks anyway !

Comment: As this updates the array in place, you may need to either copy the array to `$priceListFormat` and then apply the code to that array, or just change the output references to `$priceList`